# How to make "Upload new revision" default behaviour in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to make it the default behaviour that when I drag & drop or upload a file into a folder, using the Google Drive web client, that it automatically treats the file as a new revision if a file with the same name already exists?

Currently, what it does is to create a separate file with the same file name.

Comment: This video doesn't quite answer the question, but may be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KLKi1QCqY